# Dual US/NL citizen traveling to Edinburgh and Copenhagen

Tags: airlines, bookings, clothing, copenhagen, edinburgh

I am planning on traveling from Boston to Edinburgh early this March and then on to Copenhagen some days later. If it is relevant anywhere, I am a US/NL dual citizen. This is my first travel to either of these locations, and indeed my first travel to a European destination outside of NL.

**Travel**

Firstly, for a travel plan of US->UK->DEN->US, how should I make use of my dual citizenship? Should I use my American passport or my Dutch one, or perhaps some combination of both?

Secondly, the way flights seem to be priced on online tools is a little complicated.I have been looking at flights from Airlines like WOW, Ryanair, and British Airways.

This got me to wondering, is there an airline that is best for BOS->EDI?

One way prices seem to be around USD$50 less than two way prices BOS<->EDI, which is crazy to me. Why would airlines price these flights similarly? Why do I find that it may be similarly expensive to fly two rount-trip flights in stead of a three-leg journey?

Edited for Clarity

Comment: Welcome. You are asking many different questions here. Please split your post and restrict yourself to one question in each post. Some of your questions might also be off-topic here, like 'what is the best?' or 'is this appropriate?' (primarly opinion based). Take a look in the help center to see which questions are sutiable for this site and which type of questions to avoid: http://travel.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [I have two passports/nationalities. How do I use them when I travel?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/52100)

Comment: @Jan I just looked at that question, it had good information on how to use your passports when you have them for both the source country and destination country. It also had some good info for general use. I guess the part of my question related to passports is more specifically about using a US and EU member passport to enter an EU member country.

Answer (score 7):

Note: the UK is planning to leave the EU, at the time of writing it has not actually left yet. What impact this will have on travellers going forward is unknown. It is highly unlikely (but not impossible) that this will affect the OPs travel in march but far more likely that it will affect future readers of this answer.

> I have been looking at flights from Airlines like Wow, RyanAir, and British Airways. Is there an airline that is best for BOS->EDI? One way prices seem to be around USD$50 less than two way prices BOS<->EDI, which is crazy to me.

You want to get the two transatlantic legs on the same ticket, that way they can be priced at "half-return" rates rather than "single" rates.

There are various ways this could be done from a ticketing perspective.

1. An "open jaw" ticket that covers the two transatlantic links and nothing else.
2. A return from Boston to Edinburgh with a stopover in copenhagen on the way back.
3. A return from Bosten to Copenhagen with a stopover in Edinburgh on the way out.
4. A "multi city" ticket with the thee legs priced seperately.

I would suggest plugging your requirements into the "round trip/multi-city" options on something like google flights and seeing what comes back. I would probablly try this both with just the transatlantic legs and with all three legs.

> Should I use my American Passport or my Dutch one, or perhaps some combination of both?

By law you have to use your US passport to Enter the US.

For travel to the UK and Denmark you can use either passport but using the Dutch one puts you in a much stronger legal position. EU citizens have the right to enter EU countries while for US citizens entry is subject to the immigration officer beliving you are a legitimate visitor.

So you should show US border officials your US passport and EU border officials your Dutch passport. Airline officials should be shown the passport for the country you are travelling to.

Comment: Also, there is a separate, often quicker, queue through immigration for EU citizens.

Comment: "using the Dutch one puts you in a much stronger legal position": an EU citizen's rights do not depend on using a particular passport, only on being able to prove that one is an EU citizen.  It's certainly simpler to use the EU passport in the EU, but failing to use it doesn't mean that the person has forfeited the right of free movement.  It means that the person hasn't proved the existence of that right to anyone, but the right can be asserted at any time.  I say this to counter the common misconception that an EU citizen entering the EU with a US passport would have to leave within 90 days.

Answer (score 5):

**Ferry:** There are no scheduled ferry crossings between the UK and Denmark anymore. The closest would be Newcastle to IJmuiden, and then ground transport through the Netherlands and Germany.  This will be significantly more expensive than a cheap one-way air ticket from Edinburgh to Copenhagen.

**Air:** For the transatlantic legs, you should look into searching for an "open-jaw" round-trip BOS-EDI + CPH-BOS.  Traditional airlines will often be willing to sell this for about the same price as an actual back-and-forth round trip, but you will need to use the "advanced" or "multi-city" mode on their booking forms.

(It will *probably not* entail any savings to book the EDI-CPH leg as part of this multi-city itinerary, compared to as a separate ticket possibly on a different carrier, but it won't hurt to check).

**Passport:** If at all in doubt, have both passports ready for presentation if trouble arises. None of the countries involved will give you any trouble for having two passports.

In general you'll want to use the Dutch passport for entry/exit passport controls in any EU country (which will be much smoother than the US one, even though you *could* use that too), but the US one at *check-in* for the flight back to US (so the airline won't think you need an ESTA) and for immigration back in Boston.

**Climate:** I have lived in both Copenhagen and Edinburgh, and their climates are very similar. Both temperatures and rain/snowfall in March should be within the range of variations you would expect in Boston for the same month.

Comment: One thing to note is that if you get a BOS-EDI-CPH-BOS ticket, then you (probably) get your luggage carried for free on the EDI-CPH leg. If you book it separately, this may end up being an additional cost on an otherwise cheap flight - good idea to consider that when pricing the tickets.

Answer (score 3):

**Travel**
Neither [Denmark](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/denmark.html) nor the [United Kingdom](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/united-kingdom.html) require visas for American citizens.

Airfares are often very inexpensive in domestic Europe, so your best bet would be to purchase a round trip airfare for BOS-EDI (or CPH) and then round trip tickets for the EDI-CPH (or vice versa). In my personal experience, I was able to secure a round trip ticket from Dublin to London for 100 USD. I would explore different websites. If all you need is a seat then you should be able to find something relatively inexpensive. As for the trip from the US to Europe, any international airline should be fine. I know [Norwegian Airways](http://www.norwegian.com/us/booking/flight-tickets/select-flight/?D_City=BOS&A_City=CPH&D_Day=15&D_Month=201703&D_SelectedDay=15&R_Day=26&R_Month=201703&R_SelectedDay=26&CurrencyCode=USD&TripType=2) just opened flights from Boston to Copenhagen and you could secure a round trip ticket for less than 500 USD.

**Clothing and Footwear**
It will be cool/cold in both areas during March. Also count on rain. I would recommend something that is waterproof, and will keep you warm. Dressing in layers will be your best bet. Your list of clothing seems sufficient, but it never hurts to pack some extra undergarments.

Safe travels!

Comment: The OP states he is a US/NL dual citizen. This answer does not address this.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the Norwegian flight! Good tip and very useful addition IMO even if the answer isn't as comprehensive as some of the other answers.

Comment: I think this is bad advice. The Dutch passport is a significantly better option than the US passport for entry to the UK and Denmark. With the US passport, you have to stand in the slow-moving queue, answer detailed questions about your intentions and convince the immigration officer that you'll leave within 90 days. With the Dutch passport, you get to be in the fast-moving queue, the interview is basically "Hi, how are you? Welcome." and you can stay as long as you want. And an open-jaw ticket and single is likely to be much better than two returns.